# How to compile Python with Brython to Javascript (to run with nodejs)?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, brython

How can I use [Brython](https://www.brython.info/) to compile Python to Javascript? I want to do this on my computer, so I can the run Javascript with nodejs, eg.

```
$ python hello.py
Hello world
$ brython hello.py -o hello.js
$ node hello.js
Hello world
```

The examples on the Brython website only explain how do this in the browser http://www.brython.info/index_en.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems they are very browser oriented, there is no command line option out of the box.

You can try to use their code youself from node.js, perhaps it will work easily. It seems the `$py2js(src, module)` function does the actual conversion so maybe you can just run it with the python code string as first parameter.

Another option is to use pyjs: http://pyjs.org/   which does something similar and has command line tool to do the conversion.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to compile Python code to javascript and load it afterwards using import statement . See [brython:ticket:222](https://github.com/brython-dev/brython/issues/222) for further details. You'll have to load brython js lib in advance because , in the end, Python semantics are quite different from Javascript's . You can include compiled .pyc.js code in .vfs.js files in order to speed up module import times.

Disclaimer : I'm a committer of Brython project .

Answer (score 0):

Brython has a console that runs in the browser, but not a compiler. It is meant for you to either import your python scripts into the html file, or write your python code into the html file. See pyjs if you wish a conversion tool before the page loads.